# The line between science and philosophy - current status

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphilosophy

(I know some will reject the idea of having a "line" between science and philosophy, but I don't want these answers, let's assume there is.)

We often draw a line between science and philosophy that separates between the two fields. This line is always changing, we can see it over the course of history. My question is rather simple (or maybe not?) - where is the line between natural sciences and philosophy nowadays? Is it changing even today? If so, what's the direction it's going?

I'm sorry, I know there's some clarifications needed here, I hope you can help me clarify in the comments.

Comment: Assuming there is such a line and asking for answers excluding those contending that there isn't could be considered not seeking an answer at all.

Comment: @DallasCrenshaw no, I'm seeking an answer, and I know there are thoughts for both directions. In order to prevent having answers that won't fit my needs, I remove one line of thought from the argument.

Comment: If you can confirm or reject it by observing the outcome from a repeatable experiment - it's science. If you can conceptualise it, reason and argue about it - it's philosophy. Note the lack of a line.

Comment: "We often draw a line between science and philosophy", who are "we"? If "this line is always changing" what is the point of drawing it at all? As a convention for the sake of encyclopedias? These are main problems, what the point is of drawing the line is missing, and the question seems to invite personal opinions

Comment: @ngn I don't see a lack of line. You've made a distinction - however vague - and that's what I'd call a line. It doesn't have to be a straightforward one.

Comment: @Conifold "we" are almost always philosophers, as far as I know, but it can be pushed "back" and "forward" by the any of the two departments. I'm not saying there's exactly a point of drawing it, I'm saying it's, at least in the last couple hundred of years, if not more, had always been. Let's say Aristotle, when he defines science as every form of knowledge, wouldn't exactly have a line, but for a scientist today (at least that's how I see it) the line is definitely there, and it crosses in the "philosophy-of" questions (bordering the scientific questions, asking ethics implications, etc).

Comment: As before, you are taking your own impressions for those of others. Crossing over scientists you speak of would be first to admit that there is no such line, or that it is blurred.

Comment: +1 Shimon Malin discusses Schodinger's concept of "objectivation" where the "Subject of Cognizance" is excluded. (See Chapter 9 of "Nature Loves to Hide"). Using these concepts looks like a way to create a line between science and philosophy.  Science would restrict itself to objectivation.  Philosophy would go beyond it and include a critique of what science does.

Comment: I think the next significant issue we will face will be technology and human labor.  The cotton mills of England were disruptive, but nothing like what we are facing now. So we are in the last days of this century when we are able to peacefully ask questions like you ask. Soon, maybe within 5-6 years, things will begin to become much more "fluid". I can see some good possibilities, but I worry that world leaders are not up to the task of implementing adaptive measures.